# Java wildcards defaulted to java.lang.Object instead of upper bound

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

Given the code

```
abstract class Base<Thistype extends Base>
{
    public void addOnSomethingListener(Consumer<? super Thistype> action)
    {}

    public void foo()
    {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}

class Simple<Thistype extends Simple> extends Base<Thistype>
{

}

class Test1 extends Simple<Test1>
{

}

class Test2 extends Simple
{

}

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test1 test1 = new Test1();
        Test2 test2 = new Test2();

        test1.addOnSomethingListener(test ->
        {
            test.foo(); // VALID as "test" is of type "Thistype" which is "Test1".
        });

        test2.addOnSomethingListener(test ->
        {
            test.foo(); // INVALID as "test" is of type "Thistype" which is "java.lang.Object" instead of "Base" which is the upper bound.
        });
    }
}
```

Why is the generic type of class `Test2` not defaulted to class `Base` but instead defaulted to class `java.lang.Object`?

I provided the upper bound, but it seems that that is irrelevant if wildcards are used or when no generic is given at all.

The code in the main function should be able to be compiled if you ask me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By declaring `Test2` class without specyfing its type argument:

```
class Test2 extends Simple {}
```

you are creating a [raw type](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#What%20is%20the%20raw%20type?). Therefore the compiler treats it as an instance of `Object`.

Comment: Ok, but is there some way to default it to the upper bound... as if im not mistaken, it can never be anything else. That would solve my problem as well.

Comment: You can just add another class: `class UpperBounded extends Simple {}` and the declare `Test2` using it as a type argument: `class Test2 extends Simple<UpperBounded> {}`.

Comment: Yes, but that has no difference compared to the Test1 class.

Answer (score 0):

It does not "default to `Object`".

What actually happened is that by using a raw type (`Test2` extends the raw type `Simple`), it "turns off" all generics for that type. So `Test2`'s `addOnSomethingListener` method (which is inherited from the raw type `Simple`) actually has signature `void addOnSomethingListener(Consumer action)` (i.e. the parameter's type is erased to the raw type `Consumer`).

It just so happens that the raw type `Consumer`'s `accept` method has signature `void accept(Object)` (because it's normally `void accept(T)`, but the `T` in `Consumer` is unbounded, so when using the raw type `Consumer`, it gets erased to `void accept(Object)`.